# Access value from key in Nunjucks

Tags: nunjucks

If you have the following set in Nunjucks:

`{% set breakpoints = {
    'lap': 768px,
    'desk': 1024px
} %}`

Is there a way to access the value of width for lap, without actually looping through the values? Something like:

`{{ breakpoints | lap }}` ? I've read through the [documentation](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html) but I can't figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: `{{breakpoints.lap}}`?

Comment: @AikonMogwai nope, tried that

Comment: Try change `set` to correct js-syntax `{% set breakpoints = {lap: '768px', desk: '1024px'} %}`

Comment: Thanks that works

Comment: If you answer as a proper answer I'll accept yours, for the points if you like :)